# Misunderstanding Front Matter?

Tags: bigcommerce

Still a newbie at BigCommerce, and I'm wondering if I'm not quite getting the use of Front Matter YAML in my templates.  I'm using the Stencil CLI and trying out changes to the front matter of my main product.html template, and I'm observing the results of a request to a product page with the `?debug=context` querystring. I'm using https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/ZG9jOjIyMDcxNg-front-matter-reference for reference.

1. I'm not clear on when "Global Attributes" are populated without requiring Front Matter. For example, "categories" is populated in the debug info, even though "categories" isn't explicitly included in the Front Matter of product.html. But on the other hand, "blog" is empty in the debug info until I add a "blog" entry with "recent_posts" in the Front Matter. Then it's populated. What's the difference between the two?
2. Can data that's not in "Global Attributes" not be added to pages of other types?  For example, what if I did want the *full* content of blog posts available on the product page? Can I not add a "blog" entry with "posts" (not "recent_posts") to the Front Matter because it's not a blog page? (Attempting to do so just results in empty data for "blog" in the debug info.)